# how to adjust spinner text like Google translate?

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, spinner

I want to adjust my spinner like Google android translate

[I want to adjust my left spinner text like the right image, below the given code is my left side spinner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX32Q.png)

[image]

```
<Spinner
            android:id="@+id/idFromSpinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginStart="-3dp"
            android:paddingEnd="30dp"
            android:paddingStart="15dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
             />
```

Please help me in this project actually my task is to make a spinner like Google translate

[I want to make left spinner left side and right spinner right side margin fix it should not change on increasing or decreasing text length](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dom5D.png)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add in `android:layout_marginRight="10dp"`. Just adjust " 10dp" time and time again, good luck on that spinner!

Edit:
The solution is a good use if the left-side spinner is `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/middle_switcher` but if not. You could just use any other Layouts like the GridLayout...